# Query optimization with multiple JOINs

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-optimization, star-schema

I have a query on a fact table "foo_success" in a star schema, which has about 6 million rows. This table holds (integer) references to dimension tables and nothing else. We use MyISAM as storage engine.

The query:

```
SELECT 
hierarchy.level0name,
hierarchy.level1name,
hierarchy.level0,
hierarchy.level1,
date.date,
address.city,
user.emailAddress,
foo_object.name,
foo_object.type,
user_group.groupId,
COUNT(user.id) AS count_user_id,
SUM(foo_object_statistic.passes) AS sum_foo_object_statistic_passes,
SUM(foo_object_statistic.starts) AS sum_foo_object_statistic_starts,
SUM(foo_object_statistic.calls) AS sum_foo_object_statistic_calls

FROM 
foo_success,
user,
user_group,
address, 
hierarchy,
foo_object,
foo_object_statistic,
date

WHERE (foo_success.userDimensionId = user.id)
AND (foo_success.userGroupDimensionId = user_group.id)
AND (foo_success.addressDimensionId = address.id)
AND (foo_success.hierarchyDimensionId = hierarchy.id)
AND (foo_success.fooObjectDimensionId = foo_object.id)
AND (foo_success.fooObjectStatisticDimensionId = foo_object_statistic.id)
AND (foo_success.dateDimensionId=date.id)
AND hierarchy.level0 = 'XYZ'
AND hierarchy.level1 IS NOT NULL 
AND hierarchy.level2 IS NOT NULL 
AND hierarchy.level3 IS NOT NULL 
AND hierarchy.level4 IS NOT NULL 
AND hierarchy.level5 IS NOT NULL 
AND hierarchy.level6 IS NULL 
AND hierarchy.level7 IS NULL
GROUP BY hierarchy.level0, foo_object.fooObjectId
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

What I've tried so far:

- This is the simple join version, which equals the INNER JOIN alternative in speed.
- There are indices on all fields which are joined or which are part of a condition.
- I did use EXPLAIN on this query and found that the query cost (# of processed rows) is 128596 for the table user and 77 for the table foo_success.
- I tried to remove the dependency on the user table, which leads to a # of processed rows of over 6 million in the fact table foo_success.

It takes about 1,5 minutes to finish this query, which is far off my expectations for a data warehouse star schema optimized on read speed. Is there any way I can optimize this monster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inefficiency of the query mostly comes from transfering a lot of data you do not actually use: the fields `hierarchy.level1name, hierarchy.level0name, hierarchy.level1, date.date, address.city, user.emailAddress, foo_object.name, foo_object.type, user_group.groupId` are not included in `GROUP BY` clause, which means that the information is retrieved for each row, loaded in memory and then just discarded.

What I would recommend is to concentrate retrieving of all sufficient ids and aggregation results in a subquery and then join to the rest of the tables, so that each join would produce  not more than a single row (you can even move the `LIMIT` clause in the subquery to minimize the required subsequent JOIN operations). After that, you may discover, that you do not have some useful indexes.